The OAuth state was missing or invalid. - Github authentication
I am trying to create a web app using Angular and ASP.NET Core 8, so I can authenticate the user with its github account and then show all the repos of the user on my platform, but I am getting this error.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: The oauth state was missing or invalid.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Here is my program.cs:
using GithubActions.Server.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; // Add this line
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "GitHub";
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
})
.AddOAuth("GitHub", options =>
{
    options.ClientId = "";
    options.ClientSecret = "";
    options.CallbackPath = "/auth/github/callback";
    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize";
    options.TokenEndpoint = "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token";
    options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.github.com/user";

    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.StateDataFormat = new PropertiesDataFormat(
        DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"./")).CreateProtector("OAuth2State"));

    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:login", "login");
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:avatar", "avatar_url");
});

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200") // Replace with your frontend URL
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache(); // Required for session
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNetCore.Session";
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

builder.Services.AddHttpClient<GitHubService>();
builder.Logging.AddConsole().SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
// Add this before Authentication middleware

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSession();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseCors();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");

app.Run();

When the user logs in with github and then is redirected back to app using /auth/github/callback, I see the error shown above.
Here is my controller:
[HttpGet("login")]
public IActionResult Login()
{
     return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/auth/github/callback" }, "GitHub");
}

[HttpGet("github/callback")]
public IActionResult Callback()
{
     // Redirect to frontend after login
     return Redirect("http://localhost:4200"); // Replace with your frontend URL
}

I want to solve this error - please help me

Please delete this line options.CallbackPath = "/auth/github/callback"; in your .AddOAuth("GitHub".
